# invalid or not-yet-implemented 'Matrix' subsetting in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, sparse-matrix

When I run my shiny application, I got an error message saying

`Error in prob[tw, uni.c] : 
  invalid or not-yet-implemented 'Matrix' subsetting`

That same code ran without error when it was not on Shiny. Any idea how I can troubleshoot this?

I'm not sure how to reproduce the data here, but `prob` is of class `dgCMatrix` from the `Matrix` package, `tw` is a single integer, and `uni.c` is a numeric vector.

**EDIT:**

`sessionInfo()` output:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Singapore.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Singapore.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Singapore.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Singapore.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.10.1 Matrix_1.1-4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-6    caTools_1.17.1  digest_0.6.4    grid_3.1.1      htmltools_0.2.6 httpuv_1.3.0    lattice_0.20-29
 [8] Rcpp_0.11.3     RJSONIO_1.3-0   tools_3.1.1     xtable_1.7-4
```

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: The offending line is `pred$uni[uni.c != 0] <- prob[tw, uni.c]` .

`pred` is a dataframe, `uni` is numeric.

I have difficulty providing codes that construct all the various variables involved (all in disparate functions), I hope it's good enough to know the class and assume that all the data are available at the point of the line above being executed.

Comment: what does this give you? prob[tw, uni.c]. Also give me results of sessionInfo()

Comment: A numeric vector of length 89 (corresponding to the 89 elements in `uni.c`).

`> head(prob[tw, uni.c])`
`[1] 0.031372549 0.003921569 0.015686275 0.003921569 0.007843137 0.003921569`

Comment: A hunch: one of the variables above (`tw`) is calculated by a value passed from input in ui.R after user presses Submit button. Could it be that the error happens before any values were even submitted?  I was assuming Shiny won't execute these functions until called (i.e. after submit button is pressed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in my code that is exposed by how Shiny works.

Outside Shiny, the function where the code resides worked seamlessly, being fed input from another function in the right format.

In Shiny, I expected the function in `server.R` to receive the input after the `submitButton` button is pressed, with sensible input keyed into the field. Apparently, even before the first press of button, the default value in the input field (which was not a sensible one) was passed to my function. That default value is not well-handled by my function and caused the error. Both changing the default value, and building extra error-checking in my function, worked to solve the issue.

Apologies for the confusion; this was a learning experience to be careful with default values and with Shiny processing sequence.